# Displaying generated HTML from Javascript application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, inappbrowser

In my javascript application, which utilizes Angular.js and is built with Cordova, I have created a string like so:

[image]

Ultimately, I would like to point to a page with this code just as I could point to a file like "player.html". What is the easiest way to achieve this - will I have to use some File API to export this onto a filesystem as an html file?

I ask because I am trying to open this HTML in a new window using InAppBrowser (Cordova plugin) which only accepts URLs to files

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if [blobs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) are available in your environment, but if they are, you could use them to generate an URL in memory, like so:

```
var blob = new Blob([playerBlueprint], {type : 'text/html'});
var pageURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

They are not persistent across windows, but you can pass a script that builds them in your new window.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Blob is most likely going to work now days, Otherwise you can base64 the string and use the data URI  `data:text/html;base64,aGk=`

Comment: Curious about your technique @Endless - can you make that a separate answer and show how to encorporate it with window.open?

Comment: @Chicowitz There you have it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37882902/1008999

Answer (score 1):

As [requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870765/displaying-generated-html-from-javascript-application/37870827#comment-63215405) - using base64 instead of objectUrl by a blob

```
var playerBlueprint = '<script>alert("hi")</script>'
open("data:text/html;base64," + btoa(playerBlueprint))
```

**PS** A blob can inherit the origin those be able to use the client side storage.

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Storage is disabled inside 'data:' URLs.(…)(anonymous function) @ VM1085:1`
```

However you can still communicate with the client side storage if you talk to the opener with postMessages, but why bother - just use objectURL instead

**But** A base64 url can be safer in a way that it will protect your [CS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP)P

Comment: Good info unfortunately it's not working in my environment

Answer (score 0):

You can open the new window and write to it like this:

```
var myNewWindow = window.open("about:blank");
myNewWindow.document.write("HTML code to be displayed in the new window");
```